# How to dynamically generate form fields with angular?

Tags: forms, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have an array containing a list of my backend fields for some model

ie:

```
$scope.fields = ['username', 'password', 'email', ...];
```

How can I do the following with angular:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{field }} </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input class="form-control" 
                     type="text" 
                     required
                     ng-model="new_entry.{{field}}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the model like this:

```
ng-model="new_entry[field]"
```

Just as you can access any object property using `[]` syntax:

If you have

```
x = { name: 'Joe', age: 24 }
```

You can access a property by doing

```
x.name
```

Or by doing

```
x['name']
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WN2dc/1

Comment: So angular assigns the output of a input field to whatever you place into ng-model? It would seem that the only magic that happens is the first step of creating `x`.

Comment: Yes, angular assigns the output of a input field to whatever you place into ng-model.  The magic is that you can also change `x` in the javascript, and the input field updates automatically too.  It's two way data-binding, instead of one way.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of the above. I don't think it works as you expect it to.

Comment: Fiddle added to answer

Comment: Sorry it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/WN2dc/4/. I must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: It seems to help to add x to the scope before using it in the html: `$scope.x = {}`; Without this step I wasn't able to input any keystrokes into the text fields.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense - `ng-repeat` creates its own scope, so anything that doesn't exist in the parent scope already will only exist inside of the `ng-repeat`